# why we cannot assign value to variable after defining as global variable in global area space

Tags: c, global, assign

```
#include<stdio.h>
int c;
c=35;//**warning:** data definition has no type or storage class
int main(){
.....
.....
return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it give Warning as I mentioned in the comment. Why can't we assign a value after defining it as a global variable in global space?

Comment: Because all code is in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only assignmemnt is an instruction  and each instruction should appear inside a function body.

In global scope only a special case, initialization through assignment while definition is allowed.